# Using Case Statement in Where Clause (with column)

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, case, where-clause

I want to use a case statement in a where clause. But the where clause change depends on my equation.

For example:

**Table**

```
ID Column1  Column2
1    2         3 
2    4         1
3    5         4
4    4         7
```

**Query**

```
select * from table
where (case when column1>=column2 then column2>3 else column1>3 end)
```

**Expected output**

```
ID Column1  Column2
3    5         4
4    4         7
```

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you want your `CASE` *expression* to be:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.YourTable
WHERE   CASE 
            WHEN column1 >= column2 AND column1 > 4 THEN 1
            WHEN column1 < column2 AND column2 > 4 THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 
        END = 1
```

Comment: thanks a lot. this is what i am exactly want!
my wrong is; i try to put expression right side:) 
expression must be left side! thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `CASE`, you can use `OR`:

```
select * from table 
where (column1 >= column2 and column1 > 3)
   or (column1 <  column2 and column2 > 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM tableA A
WHERE (CASE WHEN A.column1 >= A.column2 THEN A.column2 
            ELSE A.column1 
       END) > 3
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like

```
select  * 
from    table 
where   (
            case 
                when column1>=column2 
                    then column1
                else column2
            end > 4
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

`If else` can be simulated using `Or` & `And` operator in `where` clause.Try this.

```
SELECT *
FROM   tablename
WHERE  ( column1 >= column2
         AND column1 > 4 )
        OR ( column1 < column2
             AND column2 > 4 )
```